# Can SSE (or AVX) be used to do large bsf?

Tags: performance, assembly

I'm faced with having to do a bsf (find the first bit set) in a 512bits bitmap. This is in the hot path so I'd like to see how I can speed things up.

Right now I'm maintaining a header entry to know in which 32bits block the first set bit will be found. By doing a bsf on the header + a bsf in the entry designed by the header and some arithmetic, one can can compute the bsf of the whole bitmap fairly fast.

But this obvious require to maintain the header in addition of the bitmap itself. I'd like to explore alternative. Notably, SSE or AVX, but failed to come up with a solution.

Is that possible at all ? If yes, how ?

Comment: Can vectorize the LZCNT calls using VPLZCNTD on AVX-512 (with barely any supporting CPUs) :(

Comment: Leave such an optimization to some optimizing compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok if nobody else wants to, I'll have a hack at it, assuming `avx2` available (untested because `avx2` isn't for me). No idea if this is actually faster than just plowing through 8 iterations of `bsf` on a 64 bit integer register. I have my doubts. Assume src_address holds the most significant bit. src_address + 511 holds the least.

`bsf` finds the least significant 1 bit.

We can isolate the least significant 1 bit with the formula

```
x & (-1) //Hackers Delight 1st ed p11
```

`avx2` uses 256 bit registers so we'll have to unroll to get through all 512 bits.

```c
int BSR512(char* src_address) {
    // load the data into 2 registers
    __m256i data1 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)src_address);
    __m256i data2 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)(src_address + 256));

    // zero a register for negate and comparison
    //__m256i zeroes = _mm256_set_epi32(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0); //NO
    __m256i _mm256_setzero_si256();
        
    // negate
    __m256i negs1 = _mm256_sub_epi32(zeroes, data1);
    __m256i negs2 = _mm256_sub_epi32(zeroes, data2);
    // x & (-x)

    // these should be _mm256_and_si256 to avoid casts -thanks rwong
    __m256i lsbs1 = _mm256_castps_si256(_mm256_and_ps(_mm256_castsi256_ps(data1), _mm256_castsi256_ps(negs1))); 
    __m256i lsbs2 = _mm256_castps_si256(_mm256_and_ps(_mm256_castsi256_ps(data2), _mm256_castsi256_ps(negs2)));

    // set int32 in a reg to all 1s if we found something
    __m256i mask1 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(lsbs1, zeroes);
    __m256i mask2 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(lsbs2, zeroes);

    // which of the packed ints was set to all 1s? put in a normal register
    int which1 = _mm256_movemask_ps (_mm256_castsi256_ps(mask1));

    // isolate the lowest set bit
    which1 = (which1 & -which1);
    int which2 = _mm256_movemask_ps (_mm256_castsi256_ps(mask2));
    which2 = (which2 & -which2);

    // do you have to do a dance here? Does the lowest memory address contain
    // the highest bit or the lowest bit - ask your data and change this
    if (which1 != 0) {
        // extract the 32 bit int with the bit set        
        const char w = which1;
        int contains_set_bit = _mm256_extract_epi32(lsbs1, w);

        // add number of bits in lower integers unset to bsf
        return which1 * 32 + BSF(contains_set_bit);

    } else if (which2 != 0) {
        // as above but didn't find in the first loop
        const char w = which2;
        int contains_set_bit _mm256_extract_epi32(lsbs2, w);

        return which2 * 32 + BSF(contains_set_bit) + 256;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Which compiled with `clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g -march=core-avx2 -O3`

`objdump -DC a.out` gives:

```
0000000000400a90 <BSF512(char*)>:
  400a90:       c5 fe 6f 07             vmovdqu (%rdi),%ymm0
  400a94:       c5 f5 ef c9             vpxor  %ymm1,%ymm1,%ymm1
  400a98:       c5 f5 fa d0             vpsubd %ymm0,%ymm1,%ymm2
  400a9c:       c5 fd db c2             vpand  %ymm2,%ymm0,%ymm0
  400aa0:       c5 fd 76 d1             vpcmpeqd %ymm1,%ymm0,%ymm2
  400aa4:       c5 fc 50 c2             vmovmskps %ymm2,%eax
  400aa8:       c4 e2 70 f3 d8          blsi   %eax,%ecx
  400aad:       74 26                   je     400ad5 <BSF512(char*)+0x45>
  400aaf:       89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
  400ab1:       83 e0 07                and    $0x7,%eax
  400ab4:       c5 f9 6e c8             vmovd  %eax,%xmm1
  400ab8:       c4 e2 75 36 c0          vpermd %ymm0,%ymm1,%ymm0
  400abd:       c5 f9 7e c2             vmovd  %xmm0,%edx
  400ac1:       c1 e1 05                shl    $0x5,%ecx
  400ac4:       f3 0f bc c2             tzcnt  %edx,%eax
  400ac8:       ff c0                   inc    %eax
  400aca:       85 d2                   test   %edx,%edx
  400acc:       0f 44 c2                cmove  %edx,%eax
  400acf:       01 c8                   add    %ecx,%eax
  400ad1:       c5 f8 77                vzeroupper 
  400ad4:       c3                      retq   
  400ad5:       c5 fe 6f 87 00 01 00    vmovdqu 0x100(%rdi),%ymm0
  400adc:       00 
  400add:       c5 f5 fa d0             vpsubd %ymm0,%ymm1,%ymm2
  400ae1:       c5 fd db c2             vpand  %ymm2,%ymm0,%ymm0
  400ae5:       c5 fd 76 c9             vpcmpeqd %ymm1,%ymm0,%ymm1
  400ae9:       c5 fc 50 c9             vmovmskps %ymm1,%ecx
  400aed:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400aef:       c4 e2 70 f3 d9          blsi   %ecx,%ecx
  400af4:       74 27                   je     400b1d <BSF512(char*)+0x8d>
  400af6:       89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
  400af8:       83 e0 07                and    $0x7,%eax
  400afb:       c5 f9 6e c8             vmovd  %eax,%xmm1
  400aff:       c4 e2 75 36 c0          vpermd %ymm0,%ymm1,%ymm0
  400b04:       c5 f9 7e c0             vmovd  %xmm0,%eax
  400b08:       c1 e1 05                shl    $0x5,%ecx
  400b0b:       f3 0f bc d0             tzcnt  %eax,%edx
  400b0f:       ff c2                   inc    %edx
  400b11:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  400b13:       0f 44 d0                cmove  %eax,%edx
  400b16:       8d 84 11 00 01 00 00    lea    0x100(%rcx,%rdx,1),%eax
  400b1d:       c5 f8 77                vzeroupper 
  400b20:       c3                      retq   
  400b21:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  400b28:       00 00 00 
  400b2b:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```